# Unable to Receive mail from G-mail using java program

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Unable to get the mail from gmail using java program, it's giving the following Exception

```
javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for pop3s
    at javax.mail.Session.getProvider(Session.java:455)
    at javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:530)
    at javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:510)
    at com.core.mail.ReceiveMail.<init>(ReceiveMail.java:31)
    at com.core.mail.ReceiveMail.main(ReceiveMail.java:57)
```

The code works on my laptop, however, when I execute the code in company, it's giving me the above error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the code that is giving you the error.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: It seems your missing basic authentication and setting values for properties. Please provide code.

Comment: I am also getting same error.

 Properties properties = new Properties();
 properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
 properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
 properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
 Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
 // Get the store
 Store store = session.getStore("pop3s");
 store.connect(host, username, password);

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void check(String host, String storeType, String user,String password) 
{
  try {

        //create properties field
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
        properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
        Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

        //create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
        Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");

        store.connect(host, user, password);

        //create the folder object and open it
        Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

       // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
       Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
       System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);

       for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
            Message message = messages[i];
            System.out.println("---------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));
            System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
            System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
            System.out.println("Text: " + message.getContent().toString());

        }

       //close the store and folder objects
       emailFolder.close(false);
       store.close();

    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```